# wget stdout into a bash variable and special characters

Tags: bash, variables, special-characters, wget

I'd like to use wget in a bash script.
I'd like to store the output of wget in a variable for further processing (in order not to make wget request each time I'd like to apply some formatting to the output).
Here's what I tried:

```
data=$(wget -qO- mysite.com)
```

The issue is: mysite.com's html contains special characters with respect to bash's interpreter. The output is therefore truncated somewhere.

How can I get out of this?
thanks

Comment: One alternative is to save the output in a file and then read the file with cat. Something like: wget -q0- syte.com > file . Then cat file | what u want to do

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this be a variable enclose the output in quotations:

```
data="$( wget -qO- mysite.com )"
```

To escape special characters you can use sed or printf to escape them

```
data="$( printf %q `wget -qO- mysite.com` )"
```

However it might be better practice to save the output to a file

```
 wget -qO- mysite.com > mysite.html
```

Then you can remove `mysite.html` when you don't need it.  This will help if you lose a connection to the site or don't want a http request for debugging purposes.

Comment: But... using double quotes in bash does not solve the issue. Special characters will be interpreted by bash inside double quotes...
Guess I'm going to have to use a tmp file <- I don't like it. Plus in that case, you wanna remove -O- and just do a -O output.tmp instead of using >.